# Como mostrar algo de una BBDD dependiendo de dos campos de un formulario en HTML¿? con MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, formularios

Estoy haciendo un mini proyecto en php, html y mysql. Tengo que mostrar una rutina en concreto dependiendo los valores que el usuario haya respondido en un formulario.
En mi BBDD tengo las siguientes tablas. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la tabla registro hay dos campos que me interesan para utilizar: Objetivo (perder_peso, mantener_peso y aumentar_peso) y Disponibilidad (1-5 días).
Tengo 4 rutinas por ahora, yo quiero que, dependiendo lo que elija el usuario se le muestre una rutina en HTML.
Estoy estancado en ese tema y no sé cómo seguir.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al principio del archivo tengo esas consultas, pero claro, siempre va a mostrar las mismas rutinas. No sé cómo hacer para que se muestre una dependiendo lo que elija el usuario.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: El ćodigo va como texto, y por favor, ponlo todo, tambien el del formulario. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento básico de este sitio y elaborar mejor las preguntas para que sean mejor respondidas.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas podes hacer un formulario que se envie a la misma pagina y recuperar los valores cuando el formulario se envia
Te pongo un ejemplo:

Aclaraciones: dentro de form el action define a donde redireccionas al presionar el boton de enviar (en este caso el . representa al archivo index del directorio actual.
la conexion a la base supuse que la hacias usando mysqli pero si la hacer usando mysql es lo mismo para el ejemplo, la idea es que puedas sacar el formulario, como recuperar los valores al cargar la pagina y como usarlos para filtrar

```
<form method="POST" action=".">
    <label>Objetivo</label>
    <select name="objetivo">
        <option value="perder_peso">Perder peso</option>
        <option value="mantener_peso">Mantener peso</option>
        <option value="ganar_peso">Ganar peso</option>
    </select>

    <label>Disponibilidad</label>
    <select name="disponibilidad">
        <option value="1">1 dia</option>
        <option value="2">2 dias</option>
        <option value="3">3 dias</option>
        <option value="4">4 dias</option>
        <option value="5">5 dias</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>

<?php

$objetivo = $_POST['objetivo'];
$disponibilidad = $_POST['disponibilidad'];
$filtro = "";

if($objetivo == "perder_peso" && $disponibilidad > 3){
      $filtro = "where id BETWEEN 1 AND 6";
}

require('conexion.php');
$mysqli = conectar_db();

$consulta = "select * from rtn_pplt4 $filtro";

$response = $mysqli->query($consulta);
```